# Can I use the EPL-licensed library (Paho) for a commercial project and NOT disclose the source code of the project?

Tags: software, licensing, open-source-software, commerce

Can I use the [Eclipse Paho](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.java) library (licensed under [EPL](https://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html)) for a commercial project and NOT disclose the whole source code of that project? I'm not going to make any changes to Paho code, I just want to use it as a library in an Android app. Are there precedents? I could not find the exact answer on the Internet.

Comment: As a programmer, this really gets on my nerves. What's the point of giving away an IDE/Editor and dozens of libraries ***for free*** then getting mad when people actually use it for/on work projects? Don't give stuff away for free if you want people to pay for it later on. This is no different from a bank demanding 10% more interest on a loan with 2% interest out of the blue *"just because"*. It's a predatory practice, plain and simple.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on https://opensource.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @BlueDogRanch it seems this question fits the description of the licensing tag: "For questions about permission and terms to use intellectual property"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote a letter to the Eclipse Foundation. The consultant pointed me to [section 5 in their FAQ](https://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-2.0/faq.php#epl-derivative). My case falls under the term "linking". He warned that he isn't a lawyer, but offered the following short answer:

> The Eclipse Foundation does not consider linking with EPL content to be a derivative work and so you are not required to disclose your source code.